# How can set up a file sharing server to allow remote access over a WAN?

Tags: samba, ftp, file-sharing, remote-access

I want to set up a server to allow remote access over a WAN. The purpose is to allow people to remote connect and download specific files from a specified folder hosted on the server.

Is there software available to achieve this, preferably with an interface so I can easily add and remove users, plus monitor who is connected at any time?

I have looked around and only found terminal references, and not very clear how to set up. I have a service running on my Win server, but I am hoping to move from that to Ubuntu for my file sharing.

I do not want people who access the server to have any local accounts or any access to any folder/files apart from authorised folders/files.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of file transfer do you need?  There's FTP, SSH, Sparkleshare and so on.  Even Samba, if the WAN connection is reasonable private/secure.

Comment: I need to be able to allocate accounts for remote file sharing to specific shared folders. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like samba file sharing then, which is feasible, depending on the WAN link - samba isn't something you'd run over the internet.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found: https://owncloud.com/

This is close to what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short, not very complete answer, but might get you started :

If you intend to copy the Windows file sharing method, you need to use Samba, which is the linux-version of Windows SMB file sharing.

To install it, use `sudo apt-get install samba`.

As for GUI's, I'd also recommend that you install Webmin from their website (http://www.webmin.com/) which will give you a decent access-anywhere web-based GUI for all your server components.  If you prefer to stick with the repositories, you can also try the GADMIN tools (`sudo apt-get install gadmin-samba`) or perhaps the EBOX tools (`sudo apt-get install ebox-samba`).

Samba is a pretty complex topic and perhaps others will post answers that can help, or search this site for more pertinents examples : https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/samba